# Why Autocomplete is not working in parent view using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have `Autocomplete` function in parent view and when I type in `text box` of partial view, control does not hit in `Autocomplete` function of parent view. Please guide me where I am getting wrong. Thank you.

Parent view

```
  <div id="Reports" > </div> //displays the partial view
```

Partial view

```
 <div class="ABC">                    
    <div id="A" class="container">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtA)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenAId)
    </div>  

      <div id="B" class="container">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtB)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenBId)
        </div>   
      <div id="C" class="container">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtC)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenCId)
            </div> 
    </div>
```

Partial Load

```
$('.search').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('assigned');
    var route = '@Url.Action("DisplayPartialView", "ABC")?id=' + id;
    $('#Reports').load(route);
});
```

AutoComplete

```
     $(document).ready(LoadAutocomplete);
        function LoadAutocomplete() {
        $('#Reports').on('change', '.ABC input[type = "text"]', function () {
           AutoComplete("#txtA", "#hiddenAId", '');
           });
        }

     $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#Reports').on('change', '.ABC input[type = "text"]', function () {
          function AutoComplete(txtid, hiddenID, sType) {
             $(txtid).autocomplete({
               source: function (request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                    url: '/Test/AutoComplete/',
                     data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term.replace("'", "%37") + "','sT':'" + sT + "'}",
                     dataType: "json",
                      type: "Post",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      success: function (data) {    
                       response($.map(data, function (item) {
                         return {
                           value: item.Name,
                           id: item.Id
                          };
                      }))
                },
               error: function (response) {
                  alert(response.responseText);
               },
              failure: function (response) {
                   alert(response.responseText);
                }
              });
            },
          select: function (event, ui)             {                                                                       $(hiddenID).val(ui.item.value);
     $(hiddenID).val(ui.item.id);
       },

     minLength: 1
   });

    };
   });
  });
```

Any suggestions or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is not much point attaching the plugin on the `change()` event if the textbox (its too late). You need to do it when the partial is added to the DOM. Is the partial being added initially, or view ajax?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for your time. Partial is loaded only when the button is clicked from main view to view the partial.Please guide me.

Comment: What button? You need to show the relevant code including the ajax code that loads you partial.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have edited the question. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Please take your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the plugin to your elements in the `success` callback of your elements, after the elements have been added to the DOM. To simplify this, give the textboxes a class name, say

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtA, new { @class = "autocomplete" })
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenAId, new { @class = "hidden-input" })
```

and then in your script that adds the partial to the DOM

```
$('.search').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('assigned');
    var route = '@Url.Action("DisplayPartialView", "ABC")?id=' + id;
    $('#Reports').load(route, function() {
        $.each($('.autocomplete', function(index, item) {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    ....
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    ....
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Then modify the code in the `select` function to use relative selectors. Note that the elements associated with `C` need a separate container

```
<div id="B" class="container">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtB, new { @class = "autocomplete" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenBId, new { @class = "hidden-input" })
</div>
<div id="C" class="container">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtC, new { @class = "autocomplete" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenCId, new { @class = "hidden-input" })                           
</div>
```

so that the script then becomes

```
$.each($('.autocomplete', function(index, item) {
    // Get the associated hidden input
    var hiddenInput = $(this).closest('.container').find('.hidden-input');
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            ....
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // update the value of the hidden input
            hiddenInput.val(ui.item.id);
        },
        ....
```

Comment: great help! @StephenMuecke