# Autocomplete Ajax asp.net MVC, Display text

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I am using Jquery with `Ajax` `AutoComplete` to return some data, but I'm kind of stuck with the display text.
This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#locais").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateF")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: {

                    s_localidade: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.remetente,
                            value: item.ID,
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
    });
});
```

And on controller:

```
   public JsonResult CreateF(string s_localidade)
    {
        var tblOficiosExpedidos = db.tblOficiosExpedidos.Include(t => t.tblLocalidades);
        var local = (from r in db.tblLocalidades
                     where r.Remetente.Contains(s_localidade.ToUpper())
                     select new { remetente = r.Remetente + " - " + r.Cidade, ID = r.LocalidadeID }).ToList();
         return Json(local, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

On View:

```
@Html.TextBox("LocalidadeID","", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id="locais"})
```

It does work, but when i select an item, the text of the text box becomes the key number from my table. Is there a way to when i select something, the text keep as item.remetente but saves the number of item.ID into table?

Comment: You need a separate hidden input in your view for the `ID` property, and in the autocomplete `select` event, you set  the value of that input (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122409/autocomplete-function-in-the-main-view-in-mvc/49123126#49123126) for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with the help of `'select'` 
try below approach

Your view

```
@Html.TextBox("LocalidadeID","", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id="locais"})
@Html.Hidden("hiddenlocais")
```

In your jquery define  common function that takes both hidden and text box id as parameters

JQuery:

```
function WireUpAutoComplete(displayControlId, valueControlId)
 {
  $(displayControlId).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateF")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: {
                    s_localidade: request.term
                },
                 select: function (event, ui) {
                      $(displayControlId).val(ui.item.Remetente);
                      $(valueControlId).val(ui.item.ID);
                    return false;
               },  
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.remetente,
                            value: item.ID,
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
    });

  }
```

In `document ready` call above  function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  WireUpAutoComplete("#locais", "#hiddenlocais");
});

</script>
```

hope this solve your problem. i haven't tested. let me know if you face any problems

Comment: i've tried your option, fixed 1 typo from "Remetente" to "remetente", but still doesn't work and i cant figure this out haha. Also i put id="hiddenlocais"... It still return item.ID on #locais and #hiddenlocais doesn't assume a value. In any case, your answer is pretty helpfull at least now i know where to begin. Thanks :D

Comment: Unfortunately no, it worked just as it was, when i select the item, the textbox show me the id number, and Hiddenlocais does not assume any value.

Comment: did you debug. in select .. what the value is coming for ui.item.ID? $(valueControlId).val(ui.item.ID);